# python: TypeError: function takes at most 4 arguments (6 given)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("9-6.jpg")
im.show()
im.save("test.png")
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1477, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py", line 608, in _save

    ImageFile._save(im, _idat(fp, chunk), [("zip", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 456, in _save
    e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, e, a, im.encoderconfig)

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 395, in _getencoder

    return encoder(mode, *args + extra)

TypeError: function takes at most 4 arguments (6 given)
```

Comment: Try updating your PIL library using `pip`. I tried your code and it worked well. I am using version 1.1.7. You can check the version using `from PIL import Image` followed by `Image.VERSION` in the python console

Comment: did you get a solution?

Comment: Thanks. This method is not work. My version is also 1.1.7